# I need to add two commands to this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I need add two commands to this jquery code:

```
$('.acc-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".acc-box").slideToggle();
    $(this).closest(".acc-content").siblings().find('.acc-box').slideUp();
});
```

`addClass('down')` to `.acc-title` when `.acc-box slideToggle`

`removeClass('down')` from `.acc-title` when `.acc-box slideUp`

HTML:

```
<div class="acc-content">
  <h3 class="acc-title">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text</h3>
    <div class="acc-box">
      Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic
    </div>
</div>
```

I used this code but it has a problem

```
$(this).toggleClass("down");
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5gNI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass` method to check class exist or not:

```
$('.acc-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".acc-box").slideToggle();
    $(this).closest(".acc-content").siblings().find('.acc-box').slideUp();

    if($('.acc-box').hasClass('slideToggle')) {
        $('.acc-title').addClass('down');
    }

    if($('.acc-box').hasClass('slideUp')) {
        $('.acc-title').removeClass('down');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.
I pasted the code but it didn't work.
What is the complete code?

Comment: @Aquila check the changes and let me know it work or not.

Comment: When slideToggle class is present on acc-box?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, when click on the acc-title

Comment: @Aquila when I click on acc-title and insect element I did not found those class

Comment: click on acc-title > slideToggle > change: `class="acc-box" style="display: none;"` to `class="acc-box" style="display: block;"`